# Is it possible to enable a custom keyboard in-app without a keyboard extension in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

I've built a custom keyboard extension for iOS and I want the user to be able to try it out within the hosting app to see if they like it before buying. It should work out of the box without the need to add the keyboard in Settings. Is this possible?

Comment: did you find out a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it will not by an extension. See this: [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/inputView)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can show it like a UIViewController